# Get list of dependencies in Gradle Plugin

Tags: java, gradle, plugins, dependencies

I have a gradle plugin with a custom configuration. I am trying to get a list of all dependacies that use my configuration but nothing prints to console in my project where I test my gradle plugin. My code for my gradle plugin is as follows:

```
public class TestPlugin implements Plugin<Project>
{
    public static final String VERSION = "1.0.0";

    @Override
    public void apply(Project project)
    {
        project.getLogger().lifecycle("TestPlugin: " + VERSION);
        Configuration testConfig = project.getConfigurations().create("testConfig");
        testConfig.setCanBeResolved(true);

        for(Dependency dependency : testConfig.getDependencies())
        {
            project.getLogger().lifecycle(" " + dependency.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

I have checked that my plugin works, but nothing is printing to console. In my test project the dependency that I have used to test my configuration is in mavenLocal()

Does anyone have a solution to my problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably find it easier to debug the gradle plugin while its executing. I tried this and I was able to inspect the variables as well as see the log messages (I just used System.out.println). Try adding the following to your gradle command:

```
-Dorg.gradle.debug=true
```

Example

```
./gradlew -Dorg.gradle.debug=true --console=verbose test
```

The `--console=verbose` means that the terminal will print out each task name and its resolution while its executing, this is not the same as `--info` which can be very verbose.

Before you run the gradle command, add some break points in the code where you want to debug, then start the gradle command and attach a remote debugger on port 5005. Your IDE should pause on the break point allowing you to inspect your variables and if all goes well the terminal should output your log messages too.